# connecting to server with client behaves differently from telnet

Tags: go

I want to write a simple client to [this Go server](https://github.com/dbnegative/go-telnet-chatserver). when I connect to the server from CMD with telnet it works fine i.e. when the client connects, the server asks for user name, but when I try to connect from the following client:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    // connect to this socket
    conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8181")
    for {
        // read in input from stdin
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Print("Write to send: ")
        text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

        // send to socket
        fmt.Fprintf(conn, text)
        // listen for reply
        message, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
        fmt.Print("Message from server: " + message)
    }
}
```

The server always stays behind in one message. For example, after I run the server and trying to connect from client:

Server Output:

```
D:\>go run server.go
2019/11/10 22:07:19 listening on:  127.0.0.1:8181
2019/11/10 22:07:24 createclient: remote connection from: 127.0.0.1:55565
2019/11/10 22:07:29 new client created: 127.0.0.1:55565 devy
```

Client Output:

```
D:\>go run client.go
Write to send: devy
Message from server: Please Enter Name: ---------------------------
Write to send:
```

But I want that the message "Please Enter Name: ---------------------------" from server would displayed first when client logged in

Comment: One problem is that the application discards the bufio.Readers and any data they may have buffered.  Create the readers outside of the loop.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I tried to put the reader outside loop and now I see server's message as expected, thank you

Answer (score -1):

You are reading from stdin first, and then sending that to the server. If the server sends the "Please Enter Name" string, then you have to first read from the server, and then read from stdin, and write what you read to the server.

```
for {
        message, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
        fmt.Print("Message from server: " + message)
        // read in input from stdin
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Print("Write to send: ")
        text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        // send to socket
        fmt.Fprintf(conn, text)
    }
```

Comment: I tried this already, now the looks like client hangs, without printing nothing at client side

Comment: The server first sends the message asking name, then waits for input. However, the prompt asking for input does not end with a newline. Maybe you can handle this first exchange as a special case, and wait for ':'?